# Round the end of shape (mesh)

Tags: bevel

I have created a bezier curve, applied a bevel and then converted it to a mesh. Is there a way to round the end of the shape? I have tried the bevel modifier but it didn't work as i hoped.

It is like this:
[image]

I want it to end like this:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Instead of a bevel modifier you might be better off going into edit mode and doing a bevel with Ctrl+B just on the ring of edges at the very end

Comment: Have you tried editing the mesh in proportional editing mode?  You could select vertices near the end, set the influence circle to an appropriate size and then use the shrink/fatten tool (ALT-S) to shrink the curve.

Comment: @person123 Hi, I tried to make the bevel on the ring edges but the result is very similar to what i had before.. Do you mind if i send you the file to see if you can help me please?

Comment: Hi @MartyFouts. I tried to shrink the curve but it always ends like this: https://imgur.com/a/QT0khFj                                                                                        
Do you mind if i send you the file to see if you can help me please?

Comment: i'm about to head out for the day but if you post the file here i'm sure someone can help.  otherwise i'll take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you very much! Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m74y0ea4thjmdv8/blenderfile_test.blend?dl=0  It has the original image behind the 3d one, which is what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The bevel of a curve can be given a [Taper Object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html) in its 'Data' tab > 'Geometry' panel:

[image]

The radius of the bevelled curve is varied according to the Y of the taper curve in the taper-curve's  own object-space.

As shown, the bevel can be mapped to less than the full extent of the curve, and there are various settings for the interpolation of the mapping from point to
point.

But, adjusting the number of subdivisions in the bevelled curve to capture, not only the curvature along its length, but also the variation in its radius, can be a bit fiddly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I already have the all shape with the desired radius.. I only wanted to change the terminals.. That means I have to make the shape all again right?

Comment: @Taylor Yes, but..  I'll check it out for relatively simple ways to do that? No guarantee.

Comment: Thank you :) I put the file in the post if it is easier for you to see. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/m74y0ea4thjmdv8/blenderfile_test.blend?dl=0)

Comment: @Taylor.. I maybe misunderstood your question. My approach has been to model with fewer vertices, and after conversion to mesh, repair the tips by filling the holes with  ngons, insetting those, and dragging them out along their normals, before applying a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier to make them round.  File [here](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vXB6ZRYp/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is exactly what I needed! It took me a while to understand all the steps you took since I'm new to Blender, but I managed to do everything as you said :)